# three.js canvas not visible in absolute position

Tags: css, canvas, position

I have a canvas inside a *position:absolute* element to have a grid of many objects and one single canvas.

It works ONLY if I don't apply a position to the main container:

See the example: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uncoke/uof5qxba/20/) and try it having id='stage'  and id='NOstage' to see the differences.

It works:

```
<div id="NOID">
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    <div id="content">  
    </div>
 </div>
```

It doesn't work

```
<div id="stage">
   <canvas id="c"></canvas>
   <div id="content">  
   </div>
</div>
```

In this case, the mask covers the objects.

The CSS:

```
#stage{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 900px;
}
```

[image]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: ```#content {position: relative;}``` change content position to relative.

Comment: Thanks. In this case, I see the object but the title. I need to have the exactly as the image posted above.

Comment: Add a `height` or `bottom` value.

Comment: @sol To which element?

Comment: `#stage` https://jsfiddle.net/dqh412wx/

Comment: @sol thanks, I see. Try to set the height to 150px. I would like to not cover the title just like the image above.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/csa21vup/ something like this?

Comment: @sol Totally! Thanks! It looks perfect! Going to see the details of your update. Many thanks